# template parameter default value with dependancy to deduced template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

*I am aware this question is quite similar to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65784277/deduce-class-template-parameter-with-default), however the cited post was about **class** template argument deduction. Here my question is about function template argument deduction.*

I currently have the following piece of code, which enables users to specify the algorithm a method should use in order to compute some values.
(Using a strategy Pattern is not applicable in this case for various reasons which are not relevant here)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
template<typename T>
class BasicStrategy
{
    public:
    BasicStrategy(T& i_Input)
    {
        std::cout << "Applying Basic Strategy to type : " << typeid(T).name() << " With value : " << i_Input <<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ComplexStrategy
{
    public:
    ComplexStrategy(T& i_Input)
    {
        std::cout << "Applying Complex Strategy to type : " << typeid(T).name() << " With value : " << i_Input <<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename STRATEGY = BasicStrategy<T>>
void Func(T& i_Input)
{
    STRATEGY MyStrategy(i_Input);
}


int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    double d = 24;
    
    Func(i);
    Func(d);

    Func<int, ComplexStrategy<int>>(i);
    Func<double, ComplexStrategy<double>>(d);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if it would be possible to simplify the interface of "Func()" in order to exempt the user from specifying redundant types if not using the "BasicStrategy"
For instance, the "ideal" interface would look like this (i realize this is not possible though):

```
int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    double d = 24;

    Func(i);
    Func(d);

    Func<ComplexStrategy>(i);
    Func<ComplexStrategy>(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, i could declare Func() like this

```
template<typename STRATEGY, typename T>
void Func(T& i_Input)
```

Which would not require the user to specify the type T twice, however, this prevents me from assigning a default strategy to the method, which would break a lot of existing code and making it less readable overall.

Is there a clean solution to this problem or is this a choice i have to make between the two options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a *[template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)* to achieve exactly what you want:

```
template<template <typename> typename Strategy = BasicStrategy, typename T>
void Func(T& i_Input)
{
    Strategy<T> MyStrategy(i_Input);
}
```

That way what you mentioned as ideal would work: https://godbolt.org/z/aosPzqa3r

Comment: Awesome, i've never used these before, this would have saved me so many headaches if i knew this before...
Small question though : i have seen answers where the template template argument was given a name (for instance template<template<typename X> typename STRATEGY> is there a difference from specifying a name vs not? (also the version with typename X seems to not compile in C++11)

Comment: Yes, they're quite handy. I was amazed when I learned about them, too :-)

Comment: @J.M As far as I know there is no difference, the name is optional according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter

Comment: I still have a question though (if necessary, i would make another post), If the "Strategies" have an unspecified number of arguments (For instance, lets say the user wants to create a strategy that takes a std::ratio and a typename T in order to store i_Input and later multiply it with the std::ratio), is there a way to make the template template accept an unspecified number of parameters? For instance using parameter packs?

Comment: @J.M Yes, you can just write `template <typename...> typename Strategy`

Answer (score 1):

> i realize this is not possible though

It is when you make `STRATEGY` a template template argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
template<typename T>
class BasicStrategy
{
    public:
    BasicStrategy(T& i_Input)
    {
        std::cout << "Applying Basic Strategy to type : " << typeid(T).name() << " With value : " << i_Input <<std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class ComplexStrategy
{
    public:
    ComplexStrategy(T& i_Input)
    {
        std::cout << "Applying Complex Strategy to type : " << typeid(T).name() << " With value : " << i_Input <<std::endl;
    }
};
template <template<typename> typename STRATEGY = BasicStrategy, typename T>
void Func(T& i_Input)
{
    STRATEGY<T> MyStrategy(i_Input);
}


int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    double d = 24;
    
    Func(i);
    Func(d);

    Func<ComplexStrategy>(i);
    Func<ComplexStrategy>(d);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ednEz4sdd)

Answer (score 1):

C++20 Answer:

Using a [template template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters) for the strategy and `auto` for the function parameter allows you to get the syntax you want.  Doing so gives you

```
template<template<typename> typename STRATEGY = BasicStrategy>
void Func(auto& i_Input)
{
    STRATEGY MyStrategy(i_Input);
}
```

Using your example of

```
int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    double d = 24;
    
    Func(i);
    Func(d);

    Func<ComplexStrategy>(i);
    Func<ComplexStrategy>(d);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs

```
Applying Basic Strategy to type : i With value : 12
Applying Basic Strategy to type : d With value : 24
Applying Complex Strategy to type : i With value : 12
Applying Complex Strategy to type : d With value : 24
```

Comment: That is a very clean implementation with the auto parameter!

Comment: Sadly, this implementation only seems to work in C++20.

Comment: @J.M That is correct.  `auto` function parameters is a feature of C++20.  If you are constrained to a specific version of C++ you should add that version tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may switch to use functor separating Strategy from `T`:

```
template<template<typename T> typename STRATEGY = BasicStrategy>
struct t_Func
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator ()(T& i_Input) const
    {
        STRATEGY<T> MyStrategy(i_Input);
    }
};

template<template<typename T> typename STRATEGY = BasicStrategy>
constexpr t_Func<STRATEGY> Func{};

int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    double d = 24;
    
    Func<>(i);
    Func<>(d);

    Func<ComplexStrategy>(i);
    Func<ComplexStrategy>(d);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJIA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXGJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BflxVNZn1jQTFEdGx/gEKDU0tue0jPX2l5UMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25OI8SYrEfYJhoAgls7e5iHxwQAnsmYofxXN7cEmBYyQMAKObnen2YbH2ABVfnddkwFAp9hYkXhkPViEwAcA3n8TAkrHd9qT9skvFFaBiQH8yaj0ZiCNjcW8IHCzAA2fZ4AD6AEkGBSCPM6WTCcTbvT6SN0CAUMsCC83GDDmYzLdksC3qFgAz0sh9licZg8fsiOaPs8QGqzMrVRCvuh2fMAHRQzAQeb2462/YAdUICH2ADcxF5rX6waq%2BYLhT63LL5a5aEdJfTCQARAkJbObSV/AFAkGYMGOj2w%2BG3RHI/YeYuYVTG1k59NkilUmli0n14GN5umtkc7mxoVeEXdw5EycyghyhXjhO2zXa3V11AN1RG5kms0Wx37G3mO3R32OvDOmFuj1epfHgNB0PhyP309uHkCsdKt9JkAptOTlmOZ5gWdxFsCJploCEGgq8VoVnCmzYJakKsM8QgwgASrcMLYAA4gAmi8mb6hiA54lWZxeA45q8gAYl4DCmHcEqTuBJZlvBaGVkhk4hqgF77KgnwsiQ%2Bxeuy5gjp%2BwremgDAjIB04ktKpIYdhuGEWCiHIQAsm85FsqOskASppJASxuamfcYHQRxrx2ZBcGodCOkoYw3HqTh%2BFEUcJFogahlVvJIyNskxC0QxTFgl5mkEVc%2BxRaY05WfmBJ3KESosEwoReq2k6ZTyxH7FwZjWfS6DLFSzzoMVZiSOV4pmYljGmMcVwQHgoppc1SWntgEDoN1oFSmSfXHL29BNjuLZIZ1w2TuNbiTf2M2Dh1Q2NaS5wECsDD7Bo1lZhwiy0JwACsvB%2BBwWikKgnAqpY1j7AoyyrM8Ww8KQBCaCdiwANYgOdGj6JwkhXb9d2cLwCggCDP03SdpBwLAMCIAqQJ0LE5CUGgmP0HEiJGFwwMg1gIYYpgABqeCYAA7gA8pCnBfTQtAAsQsMQFEkNRKEjRvCzvB88wxBvAzUTaJgDhC6QeNsIIDMMLQguI6QWDZUY4hq/g5wOHgIaYLDauNtL47rF9mXVJD1JRNiYseFgkPMngLBC4sVAGMACg0/TTOMLL/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqGrujtAYRgoNY1j6HgUSw5AizCbUCmcAAtHnsp%2BaYT2WFwCT7Hn/piLQlf%2Bo2O51586CGI4yAw9U0s5y4DDuJ4rR6MEoT9GUgztKk6Q5%2BMbT5JPmQzAMcSTJ3%2Bt1KMzT9xMHRd1068L6PS%2B2Ov096FMTT73MXCLK9KxrBIp0XRDav3Rw%2ByqAAHJyeecpI%2BxE3qJNXQaCAeJXAhAxKfXmLwBGWh5gAyBiDM6HBwakDdsDUg11bovxhnDb6v1Fgo3RoqYUOMIB42SFjYg4Q0KcA/l/H%2B%2BxgDIENKVV0ZheCYHwEQYgF49BB2EKIcQ4d%2BFRzUJDOOpA6bYmSO7UGHBLoYMhi/Bm454yoCoG/T%2B39f7/xKudIBICIC9koWqTYV9oH4MWAgC4WA4hejkSgtBINMG8GwbYXBMC/qkEBugpBmwn5YOhngxGcC5HsMUc/IJnjQmG05pkeIQA%3D%3D%3D)